# Mask domain email address using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, email

my client wants to mask the emails in a message, following this way:

Original email:

1 userone@domain.com

2 usertwo@domain.com.co --- > can be anything like gov.co, .com.mx.. etc

masked email:

1 u*****e@d****n.com

2 u*****o@d****n.com.co

For First case, I have this

```
string pattern = @"(?<=[\w]{1})[\w-\._\+%]*(?=[\w]{1}@)"; // ---> mask before "@"
string p2 = @"(?<=[\w]{1})[\w-\+%]*(?=[\w]{1}[.])"; // --- > mask after "@"
string result = Regex.Replace(mail, pattern, m => new string('*', m.Length));
string newresult = Regex.Replace(result, p2, m => new string('*', m.Length));
Console.WriteLine("Masked email: {0}", newresult);
```

and works fine:

[image: MaskedEmail first case]

but... doesn't work for the second case...

so, what is the regular expression that applies to both cases for mask after "@" ?

Comment: By *not working for the second case* I assume you mean because it changes `.com.` to `.c*m.`?

Comment: yeah, thats right.

Comment: Will not work always as it has many flaws. But you might get an idea from it. [`\B.\B(?=\w*(?:@|\.com))`](https://regex101.com/r/HLipR9/2)

Comment: @Gurman your solution above does work but is dependant on the `.com` being there. I've added to my solution your idea but using variable length lookbehinds (which are supported by .net). I've given you credit for the original idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Original Answer

See the edit at the bottom of my answer for the second method by which this can be accomplished in .net (much shorter).

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/hENFfQ/2)

```
(?:(?:^|(?<=@))([^.@])|\G(?!\A))[^.@](?:([^.@])(?=[.@]))?
```

Replacement: `$1*$2`

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/oeLnSt)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?:(?:^|(?<=@))([^.@])|\G(?!\A))[^.@](?:([^.@])(?=[.@]))?";
        string substitution = @"$1*$2";
        string input = @"userone@domain.com
usertwo@domain.com.co";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
 
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, substitution));
    }
}
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
userone@domain.com
usertwo@domain.com.co
```

#### Output

```
u*****e@d****n.com
u*****o@d****n.com.co
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:(?:^|(?<=@))([^.@])|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

  - `(?:^|(?<=@))([^.@])` Match the following

    - `(?:^|(?<=@))` Match either of the following

      - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
      - `(?<=@)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is the at sign character `@` literally
    - `([^.@])` Capture any character not present in the list (any character except the dot `.` or at sign `@` characters literally) into capture group 1
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `[^.@]` Match any character not present in the list (any character except the dot `.` or at sign `@` characters literally)
- `(?:([^.@])(?=[.@]))?` Match the following zero or once

  - `([^.@])` Capture any character not present in the list (any character except the dot `.` or at sign `@` characters literally) into capture group 2
  - `(?=[.@])` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a dot `.` or at sign `@` character literally

---

> 

---

## Edit

This pattern obtains the same results as my original answer (unless a string of length 2 is given: `i.e. un@domain.com` is left alone while the original answer will make this `u*@domain.com`).

C# (.net) supports variable length lookbehinds. Credit to [@Gurman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5331061/gurman) with his comment. He was on the right track, just probably wasn't aware that .net supports variable length lookbehinds.

### Code

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3A%5E%7C%40%29%5B%5E.%5D*%29%5CB.%5CB&i=userone%40domain.com%0D%0Ausertwo%40domain.com.co&r=*&o=m)

```
(?<=(?:^|@)[^.]*)\B.\B
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<=(?:^|@)[^.]*)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what follows matches

  - `(?:^|@)` Match either a start of the line assertion or a literal at sign `@`
  - `[^.]*` Match any character except the dot character `.` literally
- `\B` Match a position where a word boundary doesn't match
- `.` Match any character
- `\B` Match a position where a word boundary doesn't match

---

## Edit 2

Regex for emails containing `.` in localpart (see in use here):

```
(?<=^[^@]+)[^@](?=[^@])|(?<=@[^.]+)[^.](?=[^.])
```

Comment: thnks you so much, ummm... but this regular expression is functional just for php, no for C#... or maybe im doing something wrong ?. The result of your regular expression on C# is: *******@********.com and ********@*******.com.co

Comment: @Makitodev you can test with the [auto-generated script by regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hENFfQ/2/codegen?language=csharp). I also tested it with [regexstorm.net and it's working](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5e%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%40%29%29%28%5b%5e.%40%5d%29%7c%5cG%28%3f!%5cA%29%29%5b%5e.%40%5d%28%3f%3a%28%5b%5e.%40%5d%29%28%3f%3d%5b.%40%5d%29%29%3f&i=userone%40domain.com%0d%0ausertwo%40domain.com.co&r=%241*%242&o=m)

Comment: @Makitodev I updated my answer to include the code and a link to view it running in C# (on ideone)

Comment: @Makitodev I've added an edit that is much shorter than the original. It'll only work in regex engines that support variable length lookbehinds, but .net is one of those.

Comment: yeah, the error was mine. Thnks. This is the kind of explanation I would always like to see, especially with regular expressions, where usually they do not detail the operation and I love that because that's where really learn.

Comment: @Makitodev I'm glad I was able to help you solve your issue! Yes, there's definitely a problem right now with questions being answered without explanation (especially tagged [tag:regex]). If you have any questions about the above, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Yes. I did overlook the fact that .Net supports lookbehinds. Btw great answer and explanation. :)

Comment: Does not handle dots in username part well, as well as hyphens in domain part. E.g. `user.two@some-mail.co.uk` becomes ​`u**r.two@s**e-m**l.co.uk`

Comment: Same as @dizarter's comment here, unfortunately.  I love this answer/solution except for obvious emails such as `first.last@domain.com` result in `f***t.last@d****n.com`.  Anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: @dizarter You're correct, I added an edit for that

Comment: Thank you @ctwheels!  Enjoy your upvote. 